# MarkLogic Query By Example - underscore in JSON key not working?

Tags: java, marklogic

I have the following entry in MarkLogic in JSON format:

```
{
   "identifier":"user1",
   "attributesList": [
      {
        "firstName": "James",
        "address_1": "Farcity"
      }
   ]
 }
```

If, I'm going to query that using the below format:

```
{
 $query:
 {
   "identifier":"user1",
   "attributesList": [
      {
        "firstName": "James"
      }
   ]
 }
}
```

this will match and return back the expected result with a count of 1 because "firstName" is equal to "James".

However, if I do the following:

```
{
 $query:
 {
   "identifier":"user1",
   "attributesList": [
      {
        "address_1": "Farcity"
      }
   ]
 }
}
```

it will not give back any result even if "address_1" exactly matches which is "Farcity". I already tried this on other JSON key as well, it works fine with all except those with underscores in the key.. Is this a reserved character? If so, is there a way to escape this so that the key "address_1" or "county_state" can still be matched?

Comment: What version of MarkLogic are you using? Although not generally available just yet, I tried this in MarkLogic 8 and it worked correctly (got the result with address_1). That suggests the problem is related to the JSON facade used in MarkLogic 6 and 7.

Comment: I'm using 7.0-2.3 in which it's not working. You're probably right because I tried this with version 7.0-4 and it's working fine..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Json object converts the underscores to a double underscore

running this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
 at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

let $j :=
 '{
   "identifier":"user1",
   "attributesList": [
      {
        "firstName": "James",
        "address_1": "Farcity"
      }
   ]
}'
return 
 json:transform-from-json( $j)
```

you will get this out put

```
<json type="object" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">
  <identifier type="string">user1</identifier>
  <attributesList type="array">
    <json type="object">
      <firstName type="string">James</firstName>
      <address__1 type="string">Farcity</address__1>
    </json>
  </attributesList>
</json>
```

So try querying with a double underscores. Also If you are using Marklogic 6 or 7 it converts the Json to xml. so you could just try to query by example using the XML format.

Comment: Querying with double underscores still didn't work. It's hard to change the format from JSON to XML for me because that's how it's being used by the clients to my service-passing in a JSON QBE...

Answer (score -1):

See http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:encode-for-NCName for the exact algorithm and function used to map JSON field names to QNames